# Slow laravel dev server in developemnt

Tags: php, linux, laravel

Every few days when I open the dev server on my app I get really slow response times around 5s to show something on the screen. there are a few specific symptoms I noticed about this:

- Sometimes the page takes a long time to load, sometimes it loads without CSS
- when attempting to close the server and open it up again (by simply terminating the process) it doesn't close properly. I get the following (`Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use`).
- the issue can be fixed by closing and opening the server many times until I get a server that runs normally and when that happens it runs really fast as if there was no problem to begin with.
- this isn't related to any slow eloquent queries because my `/` route doesn't get any data from the database initially.

This has happened on two seperate laravel projects so far. so I am suspecting it's related to my linux ports and `artisan serve` misbehaving and I am hoping someone here has encountered this issue before

Comment: I think, if you did not want to debug linux networking, best way - using docker. Simple way - laravel sail instead of artisan serve.

Comment: Well ... when you encounter `Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use` do (as root) `netstat -nap | awk '/:8000/&&/LISTEN/'` (or `ss -nap | awk '/:8000/&&/LISTEN/'` if you don't have netstat installed)  and check which process is holding it - it's possible that you're trying to start two processes at the same time that a treading on each others feet ...

Comment: Can you check what the laravel logs say and share that?

Comment: which laravel version are you using ? I encountered the same issue in laravel 10 and my dev server was terminating 1 or 2 reloads of the website. In my case, the problem was related to the command.php file in the vendor folder, and I replaced that with laravel 8 command file, and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use artisan serve only in local env. For live servers (dev, stage and prod) use virtual hosts.
   Here is a most simlpe VH config for nginx

   ```
   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name your_domain.com; # Change this to your domain or IP address

      root /var/www/html/public;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust the PHP version based on your installation
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
      }

      error_log  /var/log/nginx/your_domain_error.log;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/your_domain_access.log;
   }
   ```
2. Probably your server and CDN (which provide your web resources such as CSS, JS, images, etc) are in different continent. If you're in Asia and the server is in USA, you'll need to wait until your request will be completed throw TCP connection (and it's really slow when the distance between the client and the server is huge)
3. Not for dev, but for production and even for staging you want to use SSD based hosts, or even nvme SSD based hosts, rather HDD
4. Optimize your app by artisan optimize - it's enough for your "/" route and dev env.
5. Upgrade your PHP version, the speed difference between 7.* and 8.* is not so small. In my nginx conf you see 7.4 version, it's because I generated it via AI, but upgrade
6. And the latest thing coming to my mind is small CPU + RAM resources.